# PHP copy part of remote file

Tags: php, file, copy

Is there a way to copy only a part of a file from a web address to the local working directory? I need to copy only the first page of a PDF to convert it into a PNG image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to copy only a part of a file from a web address to the local working directory?

Theoretically yes, there is a possibility to send `Range` header, and server should respond with only requested range of bytes from the file.

But in your case it is not possible, you don't know how many bytes you need to get only first page and moreover there is very high possibility that you can not open/read from incomplete file.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy part of a file over HTTP using `Range:` headers as long as the server supports it - but probably not useful for what you want to do. You could only get the first page of a PDF if you knew exactly which chunk of data you wanted (in terms of a byte range) which you can't know (or at least, it would be difficult to work out) without having the whole file.

Assuming you know how to parse a raw PDF, you could roll your own HTTP request procedure using `fsockopen()` and `fread()` etc, parse the data as you recieve it, and `fclose()` the socket as soon as you have enough - so you wouldn't have to transfer the whole file. This is quite complicated to achieve, but it could probably be done (although, arguably, PHP is not the best language for this task).

But there is no provision, in any protocol, for saying "only send me page 1".